Do we want a Big 5 tag?
We have a whole bunch of suggested edits introducing big-5 as a tag.
E.g. for the following questions:

What is the relationship between Big 5 personality and the theory of planned behaviour?
Facet versus scale prediction of Big 5 personality

Do we want this?

It was implemented as big-five with 22 questions ATM.

Personality is the broad area. so any question on big 5 should have the personality tag.  "Big 5" would be a keyword in journal articles, but it might be a bit too specific for this site.
